# Page root not showing when in edit mode of episerver

Tags: c#, content-management-system, episerver

Upon my first successful build of my Episever 7.5 project in visual studio I tried to run the web application. It showed up alright at first as I could navigate to admin-mode of the episerver user interface. But when I clicked "Edit" for edit-mode all that I got was a blank page and the root node for creating pages was not showing. This means I can not go ahead and create pages since there is no root to be clicked on. I have several page types and page templates in my application so that can not be the problem.

Does anyone have an idea of why the root is not showing?

Comment: Have you implemented the License file?

Comment: Have you checked the "Sites" tab, next to "Pages", and made sure you are on the correct language?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I have had the same problem. Nothing is showing in edit-mode. I found this:
http://world.episerver.com/Modules/Forum/Pages/Thread.aspx?id=69656

I read it very quickly but saw something about a bug in the javascripts.

For me it helped to change:

```
<configuration>
    <episerver.framework>
        <localization fallbackBehavior="Echo, MissingMessage, FallbackCulture" fallbackCulture="sv">
            ...
        </localization>
    </episerver.framework>
</configuration>
```

to

```
<configuration>
    <episerver.framework>
        <localization fallbackBehavior="Echo, MissingMessage, FallbackCulture" fallbackCulture="en">
            ...
        </localization>
    </episerver.framework>
</configuration>
```

That is: changing the fallbackBehaviour back to "en". I guess (for the moment) it has to be "en" for the edit mode to work.

Regards Hans

Answer (score 0):

This is old now, but here's an answer for a similar question, only regarding EPi CMS 9:
http://world.episerver.com/forum/developer-forum/-EPiServer-75-CMS/Thread-Container/2015/10/upgrading-episerver-9---error-in-edit-mode

I have a similar problem, which seems to go away by closing Visual Studio 2015.

I had a tip that uninstalling Web Essentials might be a solution, but alas it does not seem to do the trick.

I am posting a question on the episerver forum:
http://world.episerver.com/forum/developer-forum/-Episerver-75-CMS/Thread-Container/2016/10/episerver-edit-mode-blank/

There seems to be a bug which has to do with the "Visual Studio Web Accessibility Checker" which has been posted here: http://world.episerver.com/support/Bug-list/bug/CMS-4215 (thank you Sebastian Enberget btw).

The solution for me is to Disable the plugin.